# Django sitemap : 'module' object has no attribute 'get_urls'

Tags: python, django, sitemap

getting this error that's stopping me from progressing. Followed standard setup for a sitemap and got the following error:

```
AttributeError at /sitemap.xml

'module' object has no attribute 'get_urls'
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
import blog.views  as PostSiteMap
sitemaps ={
    'post' : PostSiteMap
}
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
    name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
]
```

views.py:

```
class PostsSiteMap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0
    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj): 
       return obj.date

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

Post models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
body = RichTextUploadingField()
date = models.DateTimeField()
tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags')
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null = False , default='images/place.png', blank = True, width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field")
height_field = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null = True, blank = True)
width_field = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null = True, blank = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def recent_posts(self):
    d = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - timedelta(days=30)
    if self.date > d:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/blog/%i/" % self.pk
```

anybody have any ideas why? thanks!

Comment: Whenever I use the sitemap module I put it in try & except clause. After the except put print(sys.exc_info()[0]) that may give you an indication what is going on

Comment: Did the answer below helped you to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is ought to the fact that you are passing inside the `sitemaps` dictionary, the module `PostSiteMap` itself instead of the actual `PostsSiteMap` class (that lives inside the `PostSiteMap` module).

First of all, your sitemaps should live in a separate file called `sitemap.py` (this is just a convention and a good pracice). This file should live on the same level as `wsgi.py`, `settings.py` etc, because it concerns the sitemap of the whole project (that's why it's called sitemap!).

In your `views.py` (which are defining the `PostsSiteMap` class) you should right something like this:

```
# blog/views.py

class PostsSiteMap(Sitemap):
    # your code as is

# This dictionary outside the class definition
SITEMAPS = {
    'post': PostsSiteMap,
}
```

Now, in your `urls.py` write these:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url, include
....
from blog.views import SITEMAPS

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': SITEMAPS}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
]
```